# useContext always undefined

Tags: reactjs

Why is useContext undefined?

Context

```
import React from 'react'

const PathContext = React.createContext()

export default PathContext
```

from a jsx file

```
import PathContext from '../../../contexts/pathContext';

.......


 <PathContext.Provider
   value={{
     paths,
     pathChecks
   }}
  >
     <MyComponent />
  </PathContext.Provider>
```

In `MyComponent.jsx` render function..

```
import PathContext from 'path/to/file';
import {useContext} from 'react';

const {
   paths,
   pathChecks
} = useContext(PathContext);
```

UNDEFINED!

What is my context undefined?

Comment: Are you importing `useContext`?

Comment: MyComponent.jsx

Comment: shouldn't it be `{useContext} from 'react'` and not `React`?

Comment: mistyped. Still happens

Comment: I should mention, I'm using redux provider too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like so:

**App.js** (or Main Component)

```js
// App.js
import React from "react";
import MyContext from "./PathContext";
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyContext>
        <MyComponent />
      </MyContext>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**PathContext.js**

```js
// PathContext.js
import React, { createContext } from "react";
export const PathContext = createContext(); // regular export

// A new component that will hold the context values and will wrap your <MyComponent>
const MyContext = ({ children }) => {
  const paths = "define your paths";
  const pathChecks = "define your pathChecks";

  return (
    <PathContext.Provider
      value={{
        paths,
        pathChecks
      }}
    >
      {children} // Pass children props
    </PathContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MyContext; // default export MyContext component
```

**MyComponent.js** (context consumer)

```js
// MyComponent.js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { PathContext } from "./PathContext";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { paths, pathChecks } = useContext(PathContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{paths} value</div>
      <div>{pathChecks} value</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

---

Here is a **[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-kare-je0o8)** example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `{useContext} from 'react'` instead of `{useContext} from React`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this example. It is working fine.

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useReducer, useState} from 'react';
import PathContext from "./PathContext";

function PathContextExample() {
    const paths = 'this is path';
    const pathChecks = 'this is path checks';

    return (
        <div>
            <PathContext.Provider
                value={{
                    paths,
                    pathChecks
                }}
            >
                <MyComponent/>
            </PathContext.Provider>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PathContextExample;


function MyComponent() {

    const {
        paths,
        pathChecks
    } = useContext(PathContext);

    return (
        <div>
            {paths}
            <br/>
            {pathChecks}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MyComponent.jsx file you should import **PathContext**